# Loop reverso selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando fazer um looping reverso na minha lista de `li` no selenium e não está rolando. Ja tentei um `reversed` na lista mas da erro.

Quero fazer o looping da ultima `li` até a primeira.

Por exemplo, na lista abaixo:

```
<ul id="lista">
    <li>Eu nao</li>
    <li>Consigo</li>
    <li>Comecar de baixo pra cima</li>
</ul>
```

Gostaria que o resultado fosse de baixo pra cima. A saida teria que ser dessa forma:

```
Comecar de baixo pra cima
Consigo
Eu nao
```

Observação: Eu não posso fazer o looping primeiro nos elementos transformando em lista para depois fazer o reversed. Pois no meu caso real, a lista de li é aproximadamente de 5000 itens. Porem os mais atuais sempre são os últimos, então não rola fazer um looping em 5000 itens transformando em lista pra depois num segundo looping pegar os últimos.

Comment: Podes fornecer o link a que estás a queres fazer isso sff?

Comment: @Miguel editei com o exemplo.

Comment: O teu código? Fiz agora um teste e resultou com reversed sem problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente não estou a perceber o problema que está a acontecer contigo, ajudaria se acrescentasses o teu código, mas aqui vai um exemplo:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportes_de_Lisboa')
lis = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#toc ul li')
for item in reversed(lis):
    print(item.text)
```

Nota: que a minha driver (`PhantomJS`) pode não ser a mesma que a tua, ajusta para a que estás a usar.